# Rails Neo4j what does mean no member 'ssl' in struct error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rspec, neo4j

I migrated my Rails 4.2.6 app from Neo4j V7 to V9. After changing some configuration I run the rspec command and all my tests are failing. The error I'm receiving is this one: 
`no member ssl in struct`. I received the error from this code:

```
it "finds amendments for a given item" do
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
  get :find, { amendment: { cid: "X1", namespace: "http://www.example.com" } }
  expect(response.content_type).to include("application/json")
  expect(response.code).to eq("200")
  result = remove_id_and_timestamps(response)

  #write_yaml_file(result, sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_1.txt")
  expected = read_yaml_file(sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_1.txt")
  result.should == expected
  #expect(result).to eq(expected)
end
```

Before the migration everything was working without errors. 
Please let me know how to fix the SSL issue as reported in the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem and I'm sharing it with everyone else which may have the same issue:
1) I run this command `rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[..,..,..]` 
2) I run  `rake RAILS_ENV=test neo4j:migrate`
After this 2 commands, I resolved my problem